# How do I do non-greedy repeated matches with scala-parser-combinators?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

With [scala-parser-combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators), how can I parse the `42` out of the following document?

```
1 Turning and turning in the widening gyre
2 The falcon cannot hear the falconer;
3 Things fall apart; the centre cannot hold;
4 Mere anarchy is loosed upon the world,
5 The blood-dimmed tide is loosed, and everywhere
6 The ceremony of innocence is drowned;
7 The best lack all conviction, while the worst
8 Are full of passionate intensity.

42
```

```
class PoemParser extends RegexParsers
{
    def textLine:  Parser[Unit] = ".*[^ ]+.*\n".r ^^^ {}
    def blankLine: Parser[Unit] = "\\h*\n".r      ^^^ {}
    def intLine:   Parser[Int]  = "\\d+\n".r      ^^ { _.trim.toInt }
    def meaning:   Parser[Int]  = rep(textLine | blankLine) ~> intLine
}

object RunPoemParser extends PoemParser with App {
    val poem =
        """
          |1 Turning and turning in the widening gyre
          |2 The falcon cannot hear the falconer;
          |3 Things fall apart; the centre cannot hold;
          |4 Mere anarchy is loosed upon the world,
          |5 The blood-dimmed tide is loosed, and everywhere
          |6 The ceremony of innocence is drowned;
          |7 The best lack all conviction, while the worst
          |8 Are full of passionate intensity.
          |
          |42
          |""".stripMargin

    parse(meaning, poem) match {
        case Success(matched, _) => println(matched.toString)
        case Failure(msg, _)     => println("FAILURE: " + msg)
        case Error(msg, _)       => println("ERROR: " + msg)
    }
}
```

The problem is of course that the `textLine` parser also matches `"42\n"`, so it greedily consumes every line before the `intLine` parser has a chance to match it.

In this simple example, I can create a special matcher just for the first eight lines (something like `\\d+ .*\n".r`). But how do I solve this problem in general? What combination of `guard`, `not`, `~!`, or other operators/methods should I use to non-greedily consume an arbitrary number of tokens before matching the one I want?